# Induced map of kernels is an isomorphism for a pullback diagram in an Abelian category.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

In [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08N3) stacks project proof, we have the following diagram (with $w$ pullback):

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}  \text{ker}(f) & \xrightarrow{i} & w & \xrightarrow{f} & y\\
\downarrow \uparrow & \nearrow & \downarrow && \downarrow \\
 \text{ker}(k) & \xrightarrow{j} & x & \xrightarrow{k} & z \end{array}$$
The vertical arrows are $e:\text{ker}(f) \to \text{ker}(k)$, $u:\text{ker}(k) \to \text{ker}(f)$, $g:w\to x$ and $h:y \to z$.

The diagonal arrow $t:\text{ker}(k) \to w$ is the unique arrow such that $ft = 0$ and $gt=j$ (obtained from the universal property of pullback $w$). Also $iu = t$ and $je=gi$.

It is said that

> It follows $giue=gte=je=gi$ and $fiue=0=fi$, hence $iue=i$.

Q: How did the author conclude $iue=i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the universal property of the pullback.  Letting $a=gi$, we have $ka=kgi=hfi=0$, so there is a unique arrow $b:\ker(f)\to w$ such that $gb=a$ and $fb=0$.  One such arrow is $b=i$, and another is $b=iue$, so they are equal.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to use the universal property of ker(f) and getting nowhere.